# unable to change tomcat url

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am facing some strange issue. I had one Dynamic Web project in my eclipse named "Services", When I start my Application the URL get formed is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Services/resource_url` i,e  IP+PORT+NAME_OF_APPLICATION+URL_DEFINED_IN_WEB.XML.

Later I copied the same project and rename the project name as "Client", done the changes in .project file of Eclipse and in .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component files too but still when I up my application the url that get formed is  is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Services` not `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Client`.

Does anyone has any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the context root setting?

Right click project -> Properties -> Web Project Settings -> Context Root

Comment: Yes, Even there I can see the name as "Client".